# Ionic Capacitor Android Plugin and Lifecycle Events

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor-plugin

Could anyone offer any general guidance on how an Ionic Capacitor can participate in Android lifecycle events, please? I need my plugin to use certain callbacks in order to properly bootstrap the host application.

In advance, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming here that you have developed your own [custom plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/creating-plugins) using Capacitor.

> I need my plugin to use certain callbacks in order to properly bootstrap the host application.

I would suggest you use the concept of Plugin Events rather than callbacks. Plugins can emit their own events that you can listen by attaching a listener to the plugin object like this:

```
import { MyPlugin } from 'my-plugin';

MyPlugin.addListener('myPluginEvent', (info: any) => {
  console.log('myPluginEvent was fired');
});
```

To emit the event from Plugin class, you can write:

```
JSObject ret = new JSObject();
ret.put("value", "some value");
notifyListeners("myPluginEvent", ret);
```

As per my understanding, the capacitor plugin will have it's own lifecycle of events. Hence, for it to interact with Android lifecycle there is no direct way as such. You would need to rely on the core Android API's to handle the lifecycle events.

Comment: I am indeed developing a plugin. Inquiring about its options for participating in Android lifecycle events.